# How to move file from HDFS to local filesystem within HUE's oozie job designer?

Tags: shell, hdfs, local, oozie, hue

Could anyone tell me what would be the best way so move a file from HDFS to my namenode's local filesystem, using the Oozie Editor in HUE? (NOT command line!)

I have already tried the following:

In my workflow, I added a **shell** node in in which i tried

```
hadoop fs -get /path/to/hdfs/filename.csv /path/to/namenode/local_fs/filename.csv
```

That did not work, so i also tried this in the **shell** node

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /path/to/hdfs/filename.csv /path/to/namenode/local_fs/filename.csv
```

Please note that the commands above have been tried and tested on the namenode's command line and they worked, but not when run within HUE's Oozie.

In fact, before I tried with -get and -copyToLocal, I have also tried

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /path/to/hdfs/* /path/to/namenode/local_fs/filename.csv
```

Since all these commands within a **shell** node didn't work, I thought might as well try using a **SSH** node

So i created a **SSH** node with the following values

```
user: yarn 
host: {namenode_ip}
command: hadoop fs -get /path/to/hdfs/filename.csv /path/to/namenode/local_fs/filename.csv
```

(I chose yarn because it seems that whenever i call "whoami" in a shell node, it displays yarn. I also made sure that /path/to/namenode/local_fs/ was owned by yarn )

But then, it displays the following:

*AUTH_FAILED: Not able to perform operation [ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=20 yarn@{namenode_id}_ip mkdir -p oozie-oozi/0001302-140930125511794-oozie-oozi-W/hdfs_get_from_namenode1--ssh/ ] | ErrorStream: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).*

I am really out of ideas and I cannot understand why we have to go through so many hoops to just move a (concatenated) file from HDFS to Local FS!!!

Could any give me a hint where I might have made a mistake? Is it possible at all to do this in HUE? If it is, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately Oozie sh and ssh don't support transfering file from HDFS to local. Depends on your problem, the following methods can be tried:

1. Write your own Java code and run it by Oozie. You can read this article: http://ehukai.com/2011/06/14/using-oozie-to-process-daily-logs/
2. If finally you need to transfer the file to some remote machine, the best way I know now is going to the NameNode Web UI (usually http://$namenode://50070), and download the file in remote machine (for example, using `wget`).
3. If the file contains the data needed to be imported to a database, you can try Sqoop in Oozie to do that.